# Doctrine instantiator don't let composer install

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine, composer-php

I updated the composer on my notebook (php7.1.7) and it updated the Doctrine/intaller to 1.1.0. And after I wanted to `composer install` on my reinstalled destkop and it says:

> Doctrine/intaller needs php7.1^, you has php7.0.8

How to revert it?

Only this notebook has php7.1^ my server, destkop and other notebook uses php 7.0

**EDIT:**
Composer update: I ran the `composer update` command

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/instantiator/issues/33 TL;DR they bumped the minimum PHP version and you cannot generate .lock files anymore from machines with previously supported PHP versions.

Comment: is there any method to bypass it?

Comment: No not really. You are basically SOL. You can run `composer update` on the target instead of `composer install`

Comment: What SOL means?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL

Comment: @PeeHaa thank you, the `composer update` on the target saved the day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but what do you mean by "I updated the composer on my notebook" ?

Did you run composer self-update command or composer update command?

The composer self-update as the command states it updates the composer itself to its latest version.

The composer update command update all the dependencies of your project for the latest version. In your case If you ran this command you need to reconfigure the Doctrine package version at composer.json to the previous version (same from your server). After that, just run the composer install again.

Comment: so, in this case, you have to get your "old" composer.json  and use it. To install packages you have to use the composer install.

Comment: `composer install` will not work in this specific case.